# Loops in Java not adhering to the condition?

Tags: java, loops, math

I've been scratching my head over why Java will go beyond a specified condition in some loops, while seemingly adhering to the condition in other loops. I know it's a lack of understanding on my part, but I'm confused as to when I should go over or adhere to the condition when I'm manually calculating code.

As an example, I've put in a short for loop which has an end result of 15 in iTotal, and 0 in iNumber. When I originally did the calculation on paper step by step, I ended up with the answers of 14 in iTotal, and 1 in iNumber. I assumed that the code would not go below one, as the condition was greater than zero, not equal to or greater than zero.

My original attempt -

iTotal 
0
5
9
12
14

iNumber 
5 4 3 2 1

```
    int iTotal = 0;
    for (int iNumber = 5; iNumber > 0; iNumber--)
        iTotal = iTotal + iNumber;
```

In comparison, the below code snippet will at 19 with a condition of less than 20, with the last statement being *value of x : 19*. I calculated that correctly, but I'm not sure why the above code ignores the condition and goes to zero, while the below code adheres to the condition and stops at 19.

```
for(int x = 10; x < 20; x = x+1) {
  System.out.print("value of x : " + x); 
  System..out.print(num2 + " " + num1);
```

Could anyone clarify how java interprets when to go over or stop at specified conditions?

Comment: unsure what you are asking.  In the first example to last number that is bigger than zero is 1.  In the second example, the last number small than 20 is 19.

Comment: Please remember to pick a best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In comparison, the below code snippet will at 19 with a condition of
>   less than 20, with the last statement being value of x : 19. I
>   calculated that correctly, but I'm not sure why the above code ignores
>   the condition and goes to zero, while the below code adheres to the
>   condition and stops at 19.

What you said is incorrect. The last statement printed is 19 but the last value of x is 20. This loop that you have given does in fact execute 20 times. A for loop in Java like the one you given has 3 components an integer to use as a count, a condition to test, and how to transform the count variable. In a general form it looks like this:

```
for(count variable, condition, transformation){
//Code goes here
//End loop
}
```

This for loops executes until the condition is no longer true, which is caused by applying a transformation of some sort the count variable.

Using the for loop you gave as an example:

```
for(int x = 10; x < 20; x = x+1) {
  System.out.print("value of x : " + x); 
  System..out.print(num2 + " " + num1); 
}
```

1. We create the count variable (`int x`) and set it equal to `10`.
2. We check the count variable (`int x`) against the condition ( `x<20` ) and evaluate the result, `x < 20 == true` so the code within the loop is run. At the end of the code, which I have marked "End Loop" above the transformation (`x + 1`) is applied to the count variable before the condition is tested again to see if the loop should proceed.
3. `x = 11` now because x was equal to 10 but we added one as specified at the end of last loop. `x < 20 == true` is still true so the code within the loop will be executed again. This is continued in this way until the last number.
4. When x = 19 we test against the condition as we have been doing and see if `x < 20 == true` is still true, which it is so the code is executed. When the code execution ends, the count variable is again incremented, `so x = 20`.
5. With `x = 20`we once again test against `x < 20`. This time `x < 20 == false` so the code inside the loop is not executed nor is another transformation applied to the variable. At this point, when the condition becomes false the loop ends. So because we said `x < 20` and not `x <= 20` on the 20th loop, when x = 20, this code:

   System.out.print("value of x : " + x); 
   System..out.print(num2 + " " + num1);

   will not run. This means that the final output of the program would occur when `x = 19` not when `x=20` although if you were still able to access the count variable after the loop ends (which I believe you can do with a debugger) you would see `x=20`

The first loop does this:

1. iTotal = 0
2. iTotal = 5
3. iTotal = 9
4. iTotal = 12
5. iTotal = 14
6. iTotal = 15
7. Loop end

also as the first loops transformation is written as `x--` instead of `x - 1` the second loop can be rewritten as:

```
for(int x = 10; x < 20; x++) {
  System.out.print("value of x : " + x); 
  System..out.print(num2 + " " + num1); 
}
```

in Java the `++` operator increments by 1, it is the same as `x+1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop

```
for (int iNumber = 5; iNumber > 0; iNumber--)
    iTotal = iTotal + iNumber;
```

is 5+4+3+2+1 = 15 (you must have printed `iTotal` before you added the first `iNumber`). Your second loop is similar the loop body isn't entered when the condition evaluates to `false`.

```
int x = 10;
for(; x < 20; x = x+1) {
  System.out.print(x + " ");
}
System.out.println(x); // x is 20
```

as 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 but at twenty the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is checked *before* each loop, not after. So in your first example, the logic would go:

- `iNumber = 5`
- first loop iteration

  - check `iNumber > 0`. `5 > 0`, so continue the loop
  - add 5 to `iTotal` (`iTotal=5` after this)
  - decrement `iNumber`
- second loop iteration

  - check `iNumber > 0`. `4 > 0`, so continue the loop
  - add 4 to `iTotal` (`iTotal=9` after this)
  - decrement `iNumber`
- ...
- fifth loop iteration

  - check `iNumber > 0`. `1 > 0`, so continue the loop
  - add 1 to `iTotal` (`iTotal=15` after this)
  - decrement `iNumber`
- sixth loop iteration

  - check `iNumber > 0`. `0 > 0` is `false`, so break out of the loop

A similar process happens with the second loop.